# How to wrap Image buttons in a horizontal linear layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Is there any way to wrap Image buttons in Horizontal Linear Layout? Or is there any other way to do the following thing?

I have six image buttons. Suppose these buttons are appearing in a mid resolution device like this:

```
Image button 1 | Image button 2 | Image button 3 | (1st row)

Image button 4 | Image button 5 | Image button 6 | (2nd row)
```

I want these buttons to appear in a tablet or any high resolution device like this:

```
Image button 1 | Image button 2 | Image button 3 | Image button 4 | (1st row)

Image button 5 | Image button 6 |      (2nd row)
```

Or like this:

```
Image button 1 | Image button 2 | Image button 3 | Image button 4 | Image button 5 | 
Image button 6 |
```

According to device screens.

Here is my main XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/back2">


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/back2">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@layout/button5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textColor="#D5D5D5"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="a150c75f96c352c"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"

                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

<org.core.mywindows8.FlowLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:f="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.core.mywindows8"
f:horizontalSpacing="6dip"
f:verticalSpacing="12dip"
f:fitContent="true"

   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/morange1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/tutorials"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:paddingTop="16sp"
        android:drawablePadding="10sp"
        android:text="@string/tutorials"
/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/mviolet"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/themes"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:paddingTop="16sp"
        android:drawablePadding="10sp"
        android:text="@string/themes"
        />
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@color/mblu2"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/gadgets"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:paddingTop="16sp"
        android:drawablePadding="10sp"
        android:text="@string/gadgets"/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/mgree"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/network"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:paddingTop="16sp"

        android:drawablePadding="10sp"
       android:text="@string/networking"/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/mblu3"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/search"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:paddingTop="16sp"
        android:drawablePadding="10sp"
        android:text="@string/win8index"/>


 </org.core.mywindows8.FlowLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can u use Relative Layout instead of Linear Layout

Comment: Hi you can use Horizontal Scroll view for displaying 6 buttons in the single row. it will be same in all the devices.

Comment: ya, but will be a bad user experience.. scrolling horizontally.. where there is blank space available..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use FlowLayout for this.

Check [this](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

**EDITED**

Add the required class, styles and attributes to your project from the link i gave you.
And use this layout, by adding it to your layout XML.

---

Mentioned in the Git Project.. Copy all the files from Git Project to your projects

User FlowLayout instead LinearLayout in XML

```
<com.yourpackage.FlowLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
</com.yourpackage.FlowLayout>
```

And then add your child view in that FlowLayout, may be in XML only or at run time.

Other Parameters supported are :

```
xmlns:f="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.namespace"
f:horizontalSpacing="6dip"
f:verticalSpacing="12dip"
f:orientation="vertical"
f:layout_horizontalSpacing="32dip"
f:layout_verticalSpacing="32dip"
```

---

I have added a support to fit the content in a line. Get [my github source](https://github.com/vivekkhandelwal/android-flowlayout)

To make this work. you need to give one more attribute as fitContent to true for your layout.

f:fitContent="true"

**Answer for your Comments**

f:verticalSpacing="12dip" - Is used to specify the vertical spacing for the whole FlowLayout. i.e Every child view/button will have the vertical spacing.

Example

```
 <org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        f:verticalSpacing="12dip"
    >

</org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout>
```

Whereas, f:layout_verticalSpacing="32dip" is specified to a child button as we specify the weight

Example

```
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    f:layout_verticalSpacing="32dip"
>
</Button>
```

Comment: how can i implement this.. plz help me.. Do i need to create another activity?

Comment: FlowLayout is a Layout like the LinearLayout. Which wraps the Button/View to next line when the available space is less.

Comment: How can i use this flow layout?

Comment: As Karakuri mentioned, this may not solve your problem since this will have empty space at the end. To make it better i have added the support to fit the content in the line.

Comment: thnx vivek.. let me try this

Comment: hi, vivek in your .java file, I am facing problem in this line fitContent = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.FlowLayout_fitContent, false);

Comment: you also need to add the resources(attrs.xml) from my github

Comment: can u plz clear me difference between f:layout_verticalSpacing  and f:verticalSpacing. I think f:verticalSpacing is for vertical spacing between two image buttons. But what is f:layout_verticalSpacing  for?

Comment: Hi vivek.. after using f:fitContent="true" a portion of the text of my image button is getting cropped. Suppose the text for a button is "Gadgets & updates" it is shoring "Gadgets &" in some resolution device

Comment: Add the layout xml to your question

Comment: I tried your layout, but have not found any cropped text. Make sure you are using &amp; "Gadgets &amp; Updates"

Comment: ya, i am using &amp;.. I have tried it in Motorola milestone, no problem is there. But in HTC V gadgets & updates get cropped. I moved the gadgets button after another button then problem solved. But how can i be sure that in different resolution device there will be not such problem?

Comment: Can i send you the .apk file?

Comment: @VivekKhandelwal : I have seen the example code. However I have a different requirement. I want to put the child view in the newline based on some business logic and hence I want to set the layout params  on the fly. It does not seem to work for me in such a use case. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would make alternate layout XML files for different configurations. Each of these folders will have an xml file with the same name (the one you use when you call `setContentView()` in your Activity).

```
/res/layout/
/res/layout-sw600dp/
/res/layout-sw720dp/
```

If your project does not have these folders, you can go ahead and make them yourself. This tells the system at runtime that, based on the smallest available width of the device in density-independent pixels, one of these three layouts will be used. `sw600dp` is recommended for specifying "large screens" like 7-inch tablets; `sw720dp` is recommended for specifying "xlarge screens" like 10-inch tablets. These numbers can be arbitrary.

You could also do as Vivek Khandelwal suggested using a FlowLayout implementation, but that may or may not work exactly as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted details for a simple and relatively concise solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23228213/2162226

---

*Summary*:

- Solution is based on this shared project: http://hzqtc.github.io/2013/12/android-custom-layout-flowlayout.html
- My post explains how to get around a bug I encountered using that example