# Custom EditText borders in android

Tags: android, android-xml

[image]

How can I get two textboxes like this in android? By using Edittext I always get a box of old style.. Please help

With the help of the following xml I got it this far:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#0193DE" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1.5dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="2dp" />

</shape>
```

How to get rid of the border lines on the top, left and right? I also want to display the hint in white color. Please help me with this too please..

Comment: add custom textfield. (with your own background and fonts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#0193DE" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

For color of hint text add this to your EditText

```
android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
```

Comment: thank you :) can you help me with the hint color too?

Answer (score 2):

You can use drawable left for this, check below sample code -

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_ico"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emailIdEditText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Edit this code and use your drawable.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to EditText containers.
Bottom line added as background:

```
TextView.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable drawable)
```

User and key icons added as drawable into EditText like in this answer:

[How to add image in a TextView text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352496/how-to-add-image-in-a-textview-text)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by changing the `targetSdkVersion` level of your project. Make it 16 or higher.

And in order to add icons in your `EditText`
just add the following attribute in you `<EditText>...</Edittext>`

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourIcon"
```

and place the icon in `drawable` folder