# Replace string in textview with image

Tags: android

I want to replace a string ({img}) e.g
"Hello {img} World" with an image.

The image isn't an emoticon and should fill the whole screen width, so the text goes on below the image.

I read about SpannableString/ImageSpan, but would it fit to my problem or is there a better solution to solve this?

The image should be loaded asynchronous using ION-Library, so would it be possible at all, if I use an imagespan?

I would be glad, if anybody would give me a hint or name a layout-element, because I have no idea where to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15352686/5232319) solution, basically you can specify an image in your textview xml, then set it programmatically.

> Try this ..
>
> ```
>   txtview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
>                     R.drawable.image, 0, 0, 0);
> ```
>
> Also see this.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html
>
> Try this in xml file

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/name"/>
```

Comment: Problem is, that I dont know how much images the API will return, so I need a dynamic solution and I need to load it from a server, so this won't be a solution.