# How to add image just after last word of multi-line Text View?

Tags: android

I am working with a restaurant application and i want Veg Non-Veg image just after the food name. I have used relative layout but couldn't able to achieve.
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMydk.png)
I want to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried android:drawableRight =@your_image ??

Comment: No idea man.. i didn't

Comment: yes i have tried that.. but that is showing image at the end of textview.

Comment: I guess someone downvoted you because you haven't showed your code, a try or something.

Comment: You can split the last line of the text view to another text view, put it below the first textview and then the image to it's right. I don't know if it's the best solution though.

Comment: but sometimes food name will only cover single line of text view

Comment: I wonder why people downvote without any prior reason, we know some are pros over here but most people who are here are trying to learn something. Anyway @ManpreetSingh, next time show us some snippet of your code.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352496/how-to-add-image-in-a-textview-text

Comment: thanks everyone for motivating me.. :) and thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a custom view like this one;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/item_image"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then your application will need an adapter to display the contents in the list or whatever view you want to display.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but again image is at the and of text view, i can achieve this using drawable right..

Comment: Yh sure, sorry for the late response.

Comment: but i want image to be sticky after text of multiline textview

Comment: Then you might want to try drawing your custom view, in this view, you make the textview and imageview as one view and the image should come at the last point of the textview.