# How to design a listview row like this

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I'm trying to design a listview row layout like this. All I could achieve was

myrow.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:text="Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit    voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo."
android:textSize="15sp"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_icon"
android:drawablePadding="5dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
/>
```

[image]

How can I fix it in this layout? Or should I go with a new design? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this answor. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15352686/4518710

Comment: Have you find the answer? If you got the answer post it. And this is nice question.

Comment: Have you achieve both above image in our single layout file.?

Comment: I have achieved the answer using the link provided by@SuhyeonLee. The marked answer didnt help me but TextViewWithImages did

Comment: Then post the correct answer here.Once again it is nice question. @playmaker420

Answer (score -1):

You can design your layout with something customized like below layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```