# How can I use Split method to find special characters and replace with images in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-edittext

I want to use split method to find special characters and then remove them and replace with images. I used html formatted texts in CDATA tag in Strings.xml file and send it to a Textview . How can I determine that special characters in that text (html formatted) in my java code and replace images and show those images between texts. 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: I want to determine where to add images in the texts so I thought to use special characters like ( and ) to find the location of where I want to show an image

Comment: This is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/21250752/4288782

Comment: Thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to search within the `String` using the `indexOf` method. Something like this:

```
String yourString = "lorem(ipsum)";
String [] charsToReplace = new Array ('(', ')');

for (String thisChar : charsToReplace) {
    while (yourString.indexOf(thisChar) > -1) {
        // do something with ImageSpan or something
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way though...