# Java: How to add a png image to the middle of a sentence

Tags: java, android, xml

It should look like this:

[image: It should look something like this]

I'm specifically using android studio. I currently have a textview and my text in the strings.xml file, but I understand there are other ways of doing the code. I have several paragraphs to write, so I figured this would be the best place to insert the text. I will need to include an image, a button, and links straight into the sentences I'm writing. (Any advice for each of those would be helpful) But, my first issue is that I don't know how to add the image into the middle of the sentence. *All relevant posts are incomplete or outdated.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add image in a TextView text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352496/how-to-add-image-in-a-textview-text)

Comment: That post wasn't helpful as it was incomplete

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use **setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()** method of **TextView**. Heopfully this will help you.
Or you can use **SpannableStringBuilder ** for this to get. I hope this will help you.

UPDATED: Here sample is available. I am attaching link as well. It will help you in your implementation

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352496/how-to-add-image-in-a-textview-text
```

Comment: Man... the documentation on the usage for this seems too vague. Maybe it's too complex for me to understand. I do appreciate your help though.

Comment: I saw this post before asking for help. It's not useful for me as I don't understand it. I can't tell which implementation is for what, some of them weren't relevant, and some didn't have useful enough comments to tell if the referenced code was relevant or useful. But, I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if you wish to display large amount of text then use something like WebView with some html template engine.

Comment: You could simply add a comment for this.

Comment: Thank you. This was useful!

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this type of code in my app but I was used dependency which I describe here...

Implement this dependency in your build.gradle file

```
implementation 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:4.0'
```

and then write this line in your build.gradle(Root level) or on the settings.gradle file

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
```

Layout.xml

```
<org.sufficientlysecure.htmltextview.HtmlTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
```

In your Activity.java file in OnCreate Method

```
TextView textView;

textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setHtml("<b>Hello</b> this is my Text <span/> <img src="yourimage.jpg"> <span/> Another Text, new HtmlHttpImageGetter(myHolder.question));
```