# How can I implement text with icon in the middle of text?

Tags: android

I need text with icon in the middle of the text for two locale like image below for example.[image]

Comment: What is the format of your string. is icon came with string format? plase share more details.

Comment: You should look into Spannables https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568

Comment: Please take a look on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352496/how-to-add-image-in-a-textview-text/38977396

Comment: @InsaneCat I have plain text and vector icon or png icon and I need to do like image above.

Answer (score 5):

Spannables can be customised to use images, aka `ImageSpan`

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan

```
 SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Bottom: span.\nBaseline: span.");
 string.setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher), 7, 8, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 string.setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE), 22, 23, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

[image]