# How to have drawable wrap with a TextView? (Android)

Tags: android, textview, imageview, word-wrap

I often need to have some piece of dynamic text in a `TextView`, with some drawable image at the end of it.

I'm having troubles making it look nice when the text needs to span onto 2 lines. I would want the image to go inline with the text.

This is what it looks like:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="This is my favourite which has a really long piece of string which will wrap"
    app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_border_24" />
```

[image: Image not wrapping]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Drawable End in a `TextView`, or putting an `ImageView` next to a `TextView` doesn't work. Is there an easy way to get this image inline with the text as if it is part of the text?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352496/how-to-add-image-in-a-textview-text#65714637), thanks to @Linh. And on the [`VerticalImageSpan`](https://gist.github.com/XiaNaLee/b7db76e9a89d516315a6)

This is manipulated to add a drawable at the end of the text:

**TextView extension function:**

```
fun TextView.addImageAtEnd(@DrawableRes imgSrc: Int, imgWidth: Int, imgHeight: Int) {
    val ssb = SpannableStringBuilder(this.text)

    val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.context, imgSrc) ?: return
    drawable.mutate()
    drawable.setBounds(
        0, 0,
        imgWidth,
        imgHeight
    )
    ssb.setSpan(
        VerticalImageSpan(drawable),
        length() - 1,
        length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
    this.setText(ssb, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
textView2.text = "This is my favourite which has a really long piece of string which will wrap "

textView2.addImageAtEnd(
    R.drawable.heart_outline,
    resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.dp_30),
    resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.dp_30)
)
```

**Result:**

[image]