# Multi row view with uneven columns, data from adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-adapter

I'm trying to create a view that would take data from an adapter and distribute it next to each other in rows. The view should rely on its width to decide when to put elements in next row. Please have a look on the ilustration, of what I'm trying to achieve.

http://i43.tinypic.com/2w327bq.png

I've found some great code here: [Android - multi-line linear layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996837/android-multi-line-linear-layout) It generates linear layouts dynamically (puts horizontal layouts inside of an vertical layout). However, I would like to keep all this data in a single view and set an adapter on it. I would be grateful for any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Code snippet from quoted thread:

```
/**
 * Copyright 2011 Sherif 
 * Updated by Karim Varela to handle LinearLayouts with other views on either side.
 * @param linearLayout
 * @param views : The views to wrap within LinearLayout
 * @param context
 * @param extraView : An extra view that may be to the right or left of your LinearLayout.
 * @author Karim Varela
 **/
private void populateViews(LinearLayout linearLayout, View[] views, Context context, View extraView)
{
 extraView.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

// kv : May need to replace 'getSherlockActivity()' with 'this' or 'getActivity()'
Display display = getSherlockActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
linearLayout.removeAllViews();
int maxWidth = display.getWidth() - extraView.getMeasuredWidth() - 20;

linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
LinearLayout newLL = new LinearLayout(context);
newLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

int widthSoFar = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++)
{
    LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(context);
    LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LL.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    LL.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    views[i].measure(0, 0);
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(views[i].getMeasuredWidth(), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);

    LL.addView(views[i], params);
    LL.measure(0, 0);
    widthSoFar += views[i].getMeasuredWidth();
    if (widthSoFar >= maxWidth)
    {
        linearLayout.addView(newLL);

        newLL = new LinearLayout(context);
        newLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LL.getMeasuredWidth(), LL.getMeasuredHeight());
        newLL.addView(LL, params);
        widthSoFar = LL.getMeasuredWidth();
    }
    else
    {
        newLL.addView(LL);
    }
}
linearLayout.addView(newLL);
}
```

Comment: Search for Android FlowLayout on Google.

Comment: @Karakuri thanks - I found this library: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout which is quite close, to what I was looking for