# Android: linearLayout. new line and specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-linearlayout, parent-child

i found this solution to the new line problem, but i cant seem to get it to work, i have been checking every comment and i cant seem to find anyone who has the same problem as me.
[Android - multi-line linear layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996837/android-multi-line-linear-layout)
I have been trying to find similar threads on StackOverFlow, but cant find any.

My code:

```
public void setUpListToLinearLayout(LinearLayout l1, ArrayList collection, String header){

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int maxWidth = display.getWidth() - 10;

    if (collection.size()>0){
        LinearLayout l1Also = new LinearLayout(this);
        l1Also.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        l1Also.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        TextView txtSample = new TextView(this);
        txtSample.setText(header);

        l1Also.addView(txtSample);
        txtSample.measure(0, 0);

        int widthSoFar = txtSample.getMeasuredWidth();

        for (int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i ++){

            TextView txtSamItem = new TextView(this);
            txtSamItem.setText(collection.get(i).toString());
            txtSamItem.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
            txtSamItem.setTag(collection.get(i));
            txtSamItem.measure(0, 0);
            widthSoFar += txtSamItem.getMeasuredWidth();

            if (widthSoFar>=maxWidth){
                l1.addView(l1Also);
                l1Also.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                l1Also.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                l1Also.addView(txtSamItem);
                widthSoFar = txtSamItem.getMeasuredWidth();


            } else {
                l1Also.addView(txtSamItem);
            }

        }
        l1.addView(l1Also);

    }
}
```

Im getting this in the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10872): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xiloandroid/activities.DetailedOpenCasesActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1297)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5235)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)             E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:742)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3509)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3380)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3325)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3301)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at activities.DetailedOpenCasesActivity.setUpListToLinearLayout(DetailedOpenCasesActivity.java:287)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at activities.DetailedOpenCasesActivity.update(DetailedOpenCasesActivity.java:242)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at activities.DetailedOpenCasesActivity.onCreate(DetailedOpenCasesActivity.java:98)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
```

i think it might be because of this line:

```
l1.addView(l1Also);
```

i have been stuck in this problem for half a day, i would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't add the same view to parent layout again and again in a loop. that causes the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Instead of this you should take a new linear layout `l2Also` in a loop, and add that in main layout.:

See this snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i ++){

    LinearLayout l2Also = new LinearLayout(this);
    l2Also.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    l2Also.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    TextView txtSamItem = new TextView(this);
    txtSamItem.setText(collection.get(i).toString());
    txtSamItem.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    txtSamItem.setTag(collection.get(i));
    txtSamItem.measure(0, 0);
    widthSoFar += txtSamItem.getMeasuredWidth();

    if (widthSoFar>=maxWidth){

        l2Also.addView(txtSamItem);  //in a new linear layout, your text will be saved.
        widthSoFar = txtSamItem.getMeasuredWidth();
    } else {
        l2Also.addView(txtSamItem);
    }
    l1Also.addView(l2Also);  // that new layout will be added in l1Also at each iteration
}
l1.addView(l1Also);  // finally add l1Also in parent layout.
```

P.S: You will need to change orientation of layout `l1Also` to `VERTICAL` for adding new layout `l2Also` in a new line.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have called `l1.addView(l1Also);` twice. in if() once and end once.
So remove this and add once again.

So call this at end.

```
l1.removeView(l1Also);
```

and then

```
l1.addView(l1Also);
```

Comment: With: 
l1.removeView(l1Alos);
i dont get the next views on the next line, so i cant really remove the view. 
Got any other ideas? :)

Comment: then remove the l1.addView(l1Also); from if() condition.

Comment: it is still not the answer, since it still only puts the one it can fit in the first line, and then do nothing. But the rest in the array still needs to be in the linearLayout, just on a new line, which does not happend this way.